# performance testing tool

Tags: ruby, watir, performance-testing

We are using watir and integrated with VS 2008 using ruby in steel and we have automated our web application and it awsome.
Is there way to use the same script to do the performance testing or is there any better tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if you want something that analyzes the performance of your website (ie: profiler) or a load/stress testing tool. I'm going to assume you want a load testing tool and not a profiler, given that you're talking about script reuse.

All load testing tools, except for one (disclaimer: my company is that one), work by recording HTTP traffic and then replaying it. The script is **very** different from a functional testing script like one you'd have for Watir.

You can either record the HTTP traffic generated by your Watir script or try to run your functional tests directly.

If you're also using FireWatir, you can use Firebug, which is an [excellent web developer tool](http://getfirebug.com) and shows you the recorded traffic for each page. If you're using IE primarily, check out HttpWatch. It's commercial, but provides [great network timings](http://www.httpwatch.com/) for IE and can export to various data formats. Alternatively, many [load](http://pylot.org) [testing](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) [tools](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) provide a proxy that can record traffic and generate a load script for you.

Once you've got the network data, you can likely quickly turn it in to a script that Pylot, Grinder, JMeter, etc can understand. The problem with this method is that you need to re-record your script whenever any part of the site or the test changes. And if your app is anything more than basic HTML (ie: Ajax, .NET viewstate, etc) then you may have to use some advanced parts of your load testing tool. See my article on [ajax load testing](http://ajaxian.com/archives/why-load-testing-ajax-is-hard) for more info.

**Shameless plug**: if you were using Selenium (or were willing to convert a couple Watir scripts to Selenium scripts), which is another open source [functional testing tool](http://seleniumhq.org), you could use BrowserMob, which provides a [load testing service](http://browsermob.com) that uses real browsers to play back the load and functional test scripts (Selenium) to drive them. It uses a lot more resources, but thanks to cloud computing the price point is still very low.

Answer (score 0):

There's [rawk](https://rubyforge.org/projects/rawk-the-logs/) that you could run over the log files. This gives a pretty comprehensive summary of what's taking so long.

Alternatively there's [NewRelic](http://www.newrelic.com/) which provides monitoring for your rails app and gives you a detailed breakdown of what every request is doing.

And finally there's [FiveRuns](http://www.fiveruns.com/) which does things very similar to NewRelic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LoadWise, you could reuse existing functional test scripts for performance testing.

With the same load test scripts without change, You can either preview it in Firefox (via FireWatir) or hit your web sites with X number of virtual users (via Celerity).

http://testwisely.com/en/loadwise

Answer (score 0):

dIf you are truely talking just 'performance' then you could alter the scripts to start capturing and recording the page load tines.  Any time you so some action that causes a page to load (like navigating to a link) Watir returns the time to load the page.

You just need to have the scripts implement some kind of simple logging method to be able to record the time to load each page, and then alter the scripts so that it return value is captured ala

```
loadtime = browser.goto(someurl)
perflogger(someurl, loadtime)
```